# Longest shared section algorithm

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

I have a reasonably large number (1000s) of strings, say S_1...S_n, where the characters take only 2 values - say for ease of visualisation " " (space) or "_" (underscore).

```
S_1:  _______ ____ __ _____ ___
S_2:     _______ _____ ___
S_3:     _____________
S_4:    ____ _____________

posi- 01234567890123456789012345...
tion  0         1         2
```

I want to find the longest stretch where 2 (or more) strings share the same contiguous length of underscores. In the case above, it is the section shared between S_3 and S_4 from positions 7 to 15 inclusive, which spans 9 positions.

Is there an efficient algorithm which allows me to find the pair (or more) of strings which do this? I don't think it's *quite* a string-matching thing, like the longest common substring problem, because these strings have a specific alignment.

Note, for what it's worth, that this is only a small part of a larger algorithm which does this repeatedly, merging together the shared lengths to form a new string, so that in the next iteration of this, I would have

```
S_1:  _______ ____ __ _____ ___
S_2:     _______ _____ ___
S_3:     ____
S_4:    ____          ___
S_N+1:       _________
```

and then I would repeat the algorithm to find (in this case) that S_2, and the new S_N+1 shared the next longest section, from positions 11-15, forming

```
S_1:  _______ ____ __ _____ ___
S_2:     _______       ___
S_3:     ____
S_4:    ____          ___
S_N+1:       ____
S_N+2:           _____
```

Then S_1, S_2, & S_3 share a section, from positions 3-6, giving

```
S_1:  ___     ____ __ _____ ___
S_2:         ___       ___
S_3:         
S_4:    ____          ___
S_N+1:       ____
S_N+2:           _____
S_N+3:   ____
```

and so on

Comment: Not really a smart or a fast solution but it might help. Convert the strings to binary numbers and compare them using `And` (bitwise operation)https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C, then go through the new created Arrays and find the longest stretch of  1's or 0's.

Comment: Yes, until I reach the max bit length. I presume there are libraries to allow arbitrary length bit arrays, though. Note that I'm happy to do this by storing intervals, rather than the strings themselves (in fact, the strings are simply representations of presence or absence of certain numbers in a list of sets.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the answer will be always between 2 strings. It is impossible to have more then 2 strings with a longer sequence than the best 2 that match if this "**where 2 (or more) strings share the same contiguous length of underscores.**' was the correct requirement. 
So the problem is a find the longest 2 strings that have the longest sequence of _ on the same position. To do this you have to do this:

1. Take each string and create another string with index pairs for each bucket of _ 
   ex: for _ ___ _____ your array of intervals will be [0,0], [2,4] [5,9]
2. Take all combinations of 2 strings and take 2 index (i for string1and j for string2). What you have to do is move each index in a smart way. First both are 0, and at each step you are asking yourself if you can intersect the interval from index i with the interval on index j, this way you have the best sub-sequence for those 2 intervals.
   After you make the intersection you have 2 options: increase i or increase j

a. Increase i if that interval it's left of the j interval

b. Increase j if that interval it's left of the i interval.

c. if their left it's equal doesn't matter who you increase.

3. Always compare the intersection found with the maximum and change the maximum if the intersection is bigger.

Optimization:
1. For each array of intervals keep the longest interval in mind that way when you have 2 strings and want to compare, if one of them has a smaller 'biggest' interval than the maximum you just don't do the algorithm, it will not improve the maximum.

The complexity it's O(N^2 * (O(len(S1) + len(S2) + ... + len(Sn)) ) because only step1 goes through all the characters. and Step 2 goes through the intervals.

Comment: "2. Take all combinations of 2 strings" - doesn't that make this algorithm at least O(n^2)?

Comment: Shot, yes, it's O(N^2 * (O(len(S1) + len(S2) + ... + len(Sn)) ). Also now that I'm thinking a faster solution might just be to put all the intervals in an array and then go through them and have 2 events happening: 0. Sort the intervals by the starting point 1. Add the start of the interval to a queue if the the starting point was reached. 2. Remove an interval from a queue then the end was reached. When you remove an interval, just check the smallest value from the queue and the difference is the intersection (You compare with max). Use a minHeap not a regular queue.

Comment: You will have to have another array of events happening. just add all the values there (Start, end of the interval and sort them) When you go through them you apply what I've said in the prev comment (Step 1 and Step2 depending on the case of the value)

Comment: And that should be (O((len(S1) + len(S2) + ... + len(Sn)) * log(len(S1) + len(S2) + ... + len(Sn)))

Comment: @Marius thanks for this, and for the follow-up. Will try an implementation and report back.

Comment: @Marius it sounds like some sort of interval tree library might help here too?

Comment: @user2667066 You won't reduce the complexity. Let's say the interval length is N. Sorting is O(NlogN) and then finding the result is just O(NlogN) again because of N query and having a minHeap search for each is logN. If you use an interval tree. You will have to do N asks but again, each ask is logN so in both cases you end up with O(NlogN) as the best aproach. I'm still thinking of something more optimal, I'll post if I'll find. Meanwhile try the aproach with sorting the intervals, it's very fast to implement vs the interval tree.

Comment: Found an optimization, because the biggest interval is the length of the biggest string you can have a look-up table that has a list of events happening at that time. You just go 1 by 1 in that look-up table (from 0 to .. len(largest_string)) and then do the operation. You will still have O(NlogN) because of the MinHeap update. but it will be a bit faster.

Comment: I have another solution just to give you more options :) 
1. Have the interval array for each string
2. Have binary Search that searches for the answer. How does this work? You have left = 0, right=len(Longest_array) and then you try to find mid as a result. If you found that you try a longer result and so on
3. For each mid what you want to do is this: Go through each value (0, len(long_str) and go through each string and see if starting from that position they have an interval with 'mid' length at least. (O(1) if you keep an index for each string. It will have the same complexity.

Comment: @Marius not yet, sorry. Will reply here when I have.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume all of the strings are the same length, although you can pad them as necessary to make this work.

Have a single array of ints, A, the same length as your strings, initialized to all -1.  The value of A[i] will be the maximum index that can be reached from i using all underscores.  That is, if A[i] == k, then there is some string such that A[i]..k in that string is entirely underscores.

```
bestOverall := -1
For each string, S:
  maxPos := -1
  for i := len(S); i >= 0; i--:
    if S[i] == '_' && maxPos < 0:
        // We were previously look at ' ', now we're looking at '_', so store
        // the highest index that happened at in this particular run.
        maxPos = i
    if S[i] == ' ':
        maxPos = -1
    if min(A[i]-i, maxPos-i) > bestOverall:
        // This is the crux of it all.  A[i]-i is the length of consecutive '_'
        // you've seen in a single string before, starting at this position.
        // maxPos-i is the length of consecutive '_' you've seen in this string,
        // starting at this position.  If this length is greater than your
        // previous best, keep track of it.  Presumably you also might want to
        // store which strings were involved, which would take extra storage.
        bestOverall = min(A[i]-i, maxPos-i)
    if maxPos >= A[i]:
        // If you're doing better with this string than previous iterations,
        // keep track of it.
        A[i] = maxPos
```

At the end of this bestOverall will be the longest run of underscores you can get with two strings.  You can keep a secondary array to track which was the first string involved and store both the first and second involved every time you update best.  This is O(N*S), where N is the number of strings, and S is the length of the strings.  Assuming your strings come in this format and not as a list of intervals this is the best you can do.  If they do come as lists of intervals then you can probably do much better.